# MySQL WHERE and Like Question

Tags: mysql

Is there a way I can combine the multiple WHERE's into one

Here is what I want to combine.

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE content LIKE '%$search_each%'
WHERE title LIKE '%$search_each%'
WHERE summary LIKE '%$search_each%'
```

Comment: Word of advice, @lone, if you ever want your databases to scale, you'll be best off steering clear of using `LIKE`. There are better ways to do it. I won't go into them here since most people who use `LIKE` are generally not DBAs anyway so don't care about scalability :-) Just a bit of advice to keep in the back of your mind for a rainy day in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AND or OR operators

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE content LIKE '%$search_each%'
AND title LIKE '%$search_each%'
AND summary LIKE '%$search_each%'
```

Comment: What is the difference in AND OR

Comment: AND and OR are the standard logical operators. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective#Common_logical_connectives

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE content LIKE '%$search_each%'
AND title LIKE '%$search_each%'
AND summary LIKE '%$search_each%'
```

This will only return entries where the content, title and summary contain the search text.

```
SELECT * 
FROM question 
WHERE content LIKE '%$search_each%'
OR title LIKE '%$search_each%'
OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'
```

This will return entries any of the fields contain the search term.

For example: Let's assume you have the following data in the order of content, title, summary
my title, my summary, my content
this is a title, this is not a title, neither is this
Not a fan, of typing a lot, so I'm a stopping now

If search_each is set to "title" and you use the AND query, you would only get back the first row.
The second row wouldn't come back because the summary [3rd item] does not have the word title in it.
If you have the same search_each and use the OR query both 1 and 2 will come back. Both of them contain the search term in at least 1 of the three columns.
If you set the search term to "a", the AND query would return only row 3, while the OR query would return all 3 rows.

The difference between AND and OR is that AND requires all the items that are "ANDed" together to be true, OR only requires that 1 of them be true.